# How do I hide "Community Wiki" questions (especially when sorting by vote count)?

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki, voting, sorting

I was just trying out the various sorting options on Stack Overflow, and one of them was "Votes".  The thing is, all of the top-voted questions are "Community Wiki".  Being a little bit of a rep whore, I was disappointed.

How do I remove CW questions from the view, so I can see the highest-voted questions that I'd get something besides warm fuzzies for answering?

Comment: You would probably have to search with wiki:0 or something like that

Comment: @Ivo: that was my first thought too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use search instead with no search terms other than *wiki:0*

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=wiki%3a0&tab=votes